# How to get /insights/page_fans_country/ with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been really desperate with this problem, I did not find an earlier post/solution for it.

So, the goal is to connect to **Facebook** (App created, token created, etc.) using PHP and access the `/insights/page_fans_country/` of a page. I am able to access my own data with `/me`, but the access token is wrong for the session and therefore the `page_fans_country` (that is a public metric) cannot be accessed.

**My code is here:**

```
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );

require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphLocation.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphAlbum.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphPage.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphUserPage.php' );

require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'lib/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

use Facebook\GraphLocation;
use Facebook\GraphAlbum;
use Facebook\GraphPage;
use Facebook\GraphUserPage;

use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\AccessToken;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

session_start();

$app_id = 'MY_ID';
$app_secret = 'MY_SECRET';
$redirect_url='http://localhost/facebook/index.php/';
$access_token = ('MY_ACCESS_TOKEN');


FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($sess)){
    $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me'); // THIS WORKS, GIVES MY PERSONAL INFORMATION!
    // $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/81221197163/insights/page_fans_country/'); 

    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    print_r($graphObject);
}else{
    //else echo login
    echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with facebook</a>';
}
```

So basically the commented request `$request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/81221197163/insights/page_fans_country/');` does not work (of course while it is not commented).

**So my questions are:**

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a command to change the session's Access Token?
- What is the best way to get the `/insights/page_fans_country/` values with PHP?

Thank you in advance for every reply!

Roni

Comment: You need to request `read_insights` permission from the user first.

Comment: What about the fact that Facebook made the metric **page_fans_country** public ("can be accessed with any access token")?

Comment: This may be related to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1413708675600278/. You can always comment on that report with related information.